How to get spl token price or market cap
I work on wallet tracker on solana, I want have there all features or types of transactions. Now I fight with how to fetch Market Cap of coin on dex platforms like pump fun, raydium etc.

you can use gecko terminal dex API, tried it myself it can fetch even the newly created tokens on chain
https://www.geckoterminal.com/dex-api


I already tried this method before, but It cannot fetch newly created tokens like on pump.fun, when I request query then I got 404 not found.

Yeah, because gecko does not support pump fun dex

Last time i was using it it worked for me, however if you specifically wanna fetch pumpfun tokens you can use pf frontend api, there are much more metadas than geckoterminal offers, but they only offer it for pf tokens, and if you wanna fetch tokens apart from pf you can use geckoterminal api and pf api at the same time you just need to code your own logic to deteck a pf token, easy way is to fetch token pool, which is also include in pf frontend api metadatas, if the token has pf pool then use pf frontend api, else use geckoterminal

All good now, I found good API for pump.fun - https://frontend-api.pump.fun/api/

Thats great, thank you for posting the link so it can help others, there some others pumpfun apis like pumpportal API, you can check that out i think they offer smaller fees for using the API, but i dont remember so cant say for sure
